# How to Start Pause and Stop thread in Java in proper way

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I started "play" with Threads in Java
and wondering about my solution with starting pausing and stopping thread...

Start and Pause works everytime (i think) fine, but when i do Stop method i get Exception:

> java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

but is stopped after that (i think so)

this is my super simple code :)

code snippet with buttons:

```
        var ref = new Object() {
            Thread th = new Thread(main);
        };

        startItem.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (ref.th.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
                ref.th.start();
            else
                main.setPaused(false);
        });

        pauseItem.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (ref.th.getState() == Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING)
                main.setPaused(true);
        });

        stopItem.addActionListener(e -> {
            main.setRunning(false);
            ref.th.interrupt();
            ref.th = new Thread(main);
        });
```

and here my Runnable class:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running;
    private volatile boolean paused;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Logger.info("MONITORING STARTED");
        running = true;
        paused = false;
        int counter = 0;
        while (running) {
            if (!paused) {
                sleep();
                System.out.println("thread working: " + counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        if(!running)
            Logger.info("MONITORING STOPPED");
        this.running = running;
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        if(paused)
            Logger.info("APPLICATION PAUSED = TRUE (paused)");
        else
            Logger.info("APPLICATION PAUSED = FALSE (continues to work...)");
        this.paused = paused;
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Or is this a stupid approach and should I do it differently to make it correct?

Whenever I "sweat out" some code, I wonder if I'm doing it in a nice and correct way... it's rather a sign of a lack of skills and professionalism :(

Thank you in advance for your help and patience and sorry for my english. :) Regards.

Comment: I've been coding professionally for 23 years, I still wonder if I'm doing it "correctly".  You should look at "thread locks" - see [Concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) for more details - essentially, when you "pause" the thread, it should be placed into a "wait" state so that it doesn't consume any resources (a free wheeling loop will consume a surprising amount of runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is printing the error message because you wrote `ex.printStackTrace()`. That's what `printStackTrace()` is for: You use it to call attention to an unexpected exception.

But if your other thread calls `ref.th.interrupt()`, then is the exception really unexpected? There's no rule that says you must call `printStackTrace()` every time your code handles an exception. It looks like you're already using Log4J, so one option would be to call `Logger.info("interrupted", ex)`. Another option would be to simply do nothing at all in the handler, because after the handler is finished, the thread eventually* will check the `running` flag.

---

* Personally, I would move the `sleep()` call to the bottom of the loop because that way, if the `sleep()` is interrupted, it won't print "working" or increment the counter again until the thread is un-paused.

```java
while (running) {
    if (!paused) {
        System.out.println("thread working: " + counter);
        counter++;
        sleep();
    }
}
```

Better still: Move the `sleep()` out of the `if` statement, so that the thread will not consume 100% CPU time (as mentioned in a comment by @MadProgrammer) while it is "paused."

```java
while (running) {
    if (!paused) {
        System.out.println("thread working: " + counter);
        counter++;
    }
    sleep();
}
```